# WCF Service works with IIS Express but Not IIS7 on server (same domain)

Tags: iis-7.5, wcf-data-services, iis-express

Following several walkthroughs I created a WCF Service using EF to connect the Northwind db. Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server 2012 Express and IIS 7.5 Express on a single development machine were used.

Using IE9 I am able to connect to the service and request individual tables as in:

[image]

Further, using OData Explorer (a Silverlight Application) I can add a new connection to the local IIS and also see the Northwind tables; for example the employees table:

[image]

However, when I move the service to a server on the same domain running IIS 7.0, I can browse to the service root as below:

[image]

However, whe I request the Customers table there is no response from the service:

[image]

And while I can create the new connection in OData Explorer, when I request a single table, an unknown error ocurrs:

[image]

The full description of the error is shown but the link is outdated and not available:

> [HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer]
>   Arguments: NotFound
>   Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.1.10411.0&File=System.Windows.dll&Key=HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer
>   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at SL_OData_Explorer.Views.ODataExplorer.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<>c__DisplayClass20.b__1d()

After googling around, I came across several posts relating that clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml files should be placed at the root of the website. And while I understand this is specific to silverlight and did place said files, they had, as expected no effect.

When I compare the Response from the local machine:

[image]

to that of IIS on the server, case it is clear that the service is there but it can't find the tables.

[image]

So, in both cases I can browse to the root of the service but only locally can I get beyond the root and look at individual tables.

It would appear to be a configuration issue to be sure but trying to find information on this undisclosed error is difficult at best. Does anyone have any idea what's going on in this instance?

Thanks,

Greg

Comment: Can you try with Fiddler so that we can get more detail about what's going on? Also, some URLs on IIS are case sensitive, so the trace you're looking at in the IE developer tools may be due to the lack of a capital C. See http://www.bitwhys.com/odata-101-constructing-http-requests-with-fiddler/ for guidance on how to do your Fiddler traces.